# Determine if a polygon of one layer covers a polygon of second layer

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, geometry

I am looking for a command for an extra column ("Reference") to list Polygons of Layer1 as "1" if they cover Polygons of Layer2. If not they shall be listed as "0".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`overlay_intersects( 'layer2' )` will return True if it does, else False which will become 1/0 for a integer field:
[image]